# is it possible to update the data (from API) with the "nuxt generate" command in "target: static" mode without "build"?

Tags: nuxt.js

my generated .html file always keeps the old data, is there a solution or am I obliged to launch the "build" each time ?

```
routes: function (callback) {
    var _routes = []
...
    axios.all(requests).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
      responses.forEach((response, key) => {
        // fresh data is well recovered
        _routes.concat(generateRoutes(_routes, routes[key], response))
      })
      callback(null, _routes)
    })).catch(callback)            
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the data when the user enters your site, I'm afraid that the 'npm run generate' command will not be useful to you since it is intended to generate sites that don't change at all.

For production, you will have to stick to the 'npm run build' (run it only once) and then the 'npm run start' command to init the server.

For development, just simple use the 'npm run dev' command and you will get a server with hot reload as you write your code.